# json viewer library for php

Tags: php, json

I would like to show my json string like this :

[image]

but if I echo my json output it shows like this:

```
{"Status":2,"TokenReg":"eeea7930efeb7715697a2035fcee3fdf","AllScores":"305","User_ID":"16433"}
```

is there any plugin/library to show json string as well as above image (formatted json) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) in PHP you can specify the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option.

```
echo json_encode(["foo" => ["bar" => ["baz" => "quix"]]], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This gives you output like this.

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": "quix"
        }
    }
}
```

If what you already have is a string you can just decode first and the encode.

```
$str = '{"Status":2,"TokenReg":"eeea7930efeb7715697a2035fcee3fdf","AllScores":"305","User_ID":"16433"}';
echo json_encode(json_decode($str), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This should give you the desired output.

```
{
    "Status": 2,
    "TokenReg": "eeea7930efeb7715697a2035fcee3fdf",
    "AllScores": "305",
    "User_ID": "16433"
}
```

Comment: my string stored in database as json string .

Comment: That's fine. You can still `json_decode` and then `json_encode` with pretty print if you want.

Comment: But you really shouldn't be storing JSON in your database. At least not in a relational database. JSON is a serialization format and that typically doesn't lend itself to data normalization. You normally deal with unserialized data and then only serialize it on output, not store serialized data and then derserialize it during processing.

Comment: is `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` related to php version ? when I use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, my output shows nothing . :-?

Comment: Yes, that's why included the [link to the manual](http://php.net/json-encode#refsect1-function.json-encode-changelog) in my answer. It's available since PHP 5.4.0, but honestly if you're using anything older than that **you really need to upgrade**. [Any version of PHP less than 5.6.0 is currently EOL (i.e. not supported anymore)](http://php.net/eol).